# Increasing speed of WiFi Local LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, network-shares

I have [Tp-Link router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WR941ND_V5.html) to which I connect my laptop (Dell XPS 15, Core i7, 12 GB RAM, Windows 8.1) and mobile (Nexus 6).

I get torrent download speed at least 2 Mbps. So downloading a file say 600MB completes in few minutes. However when I try to copy a file from my mobile to PC's shared folder (using ES Explorer) or from PC's shared folder to mobile (using ES Explorer), it takes almost 12+ minutes to complete it.

How can I speedup this? What might be the bottleneck here?

Comment: The bottlenecks are your phone and not using FTP.

Comment: Ok in phone what? Android OS, Nexus hardware, ES Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you are downloading file using torrent, every packet comes from WAN interface of your router (probably wired connection) and is sent to your computer via radio link - in this scenario every packet is sent wirelessly only once (from router to computer). When you are copying from computer to phone (or from phone to computer) every packet is sent at first to router and router sends this packet to destination device - it means every packet is sent wirelessly twice. Because the wireless channel is shared, the time needed to send this packet is two times longer (or even more). In most cases every packet comes after a short break, and every packet is confirmed by ACK frame. It takes time. [CSMA/CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance) is a protocol used for accessing the medium (wireless channel) in Wi-Fi networks.
2. Most computers has better (more powerful) wireless network cards and better antennas than mobile phones. It means that if you have computer and mobile phone placed in the same distance from router probably the downloading (or uploading) speed will be smaller in mobile phone. Sometimes, because the mobile phone is less powerfull, other stations can't "hear it" and they try to transmit in the same time making a collision. So the frame must be retransmitted. This is called hidden node problem.
3. And of course the protocol. Different protocols (FTP, Samba etc.) have different performance. Samba (Windows sharing) is IMHO very slow in comparison to FTP. Maybe try other protocol (install FTP server on your computer).

You can check what is the main reason of this slow speed very easy. Just connect your computer to your router via cable. The speed should be better after that. But if the difference will be small it would mean that the problem is probably in protocol. 
Try also placing your mobile phone near the router. It will also make speed better.

Comment: Yep I guess the ES Explorer internally uses Samba which was the culprit. I tried with [WiFi FTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nalic.app.wifishare&hl=en) android app and my Windows PC running WinSCP, and it was able to reach 4MBps+ speed, moving 800 MB file took max 3 minutes. So that was quite satisfactory. Any other suggestions to increase the speed further?

Comment: Check on other radio channel. Maybe the channel you are using now is also used by other networks (your neighbors). But 4 MBps is 32 Mbps and it is quite good result for 2,4 GHz with two stations transmitting to each other.

Comment: Hi can you elaborate on radio channel thingy?

Comment: There are 13 (in Japan 14) radio channels in 2.4 GHz band that are 20 MHz wide, but the distance between channels is only 5 MHz. It means that channels are overlapping. So check other channel 1-13. Maybe you will find channel which will give you better performance.